# Qt GUI doesn't work with std::thread as I expect

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11

The core of my project is independent of GUI framework that's why I prefer std::thread. But Qt gives me an error when thread is using.

> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.
>
> Signal name: SIGSEGV
>   Signal meaning: Segmentation fault

```
//MainWindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

struct Observer
{
    virtual void notify() = 0;
};

class Core
{
public:
    std::thread *run()
        {
            std::thread thread(&Core::runP, this);
            thread.detach();
            return &thread;
        }

    void setObserver(Observer *observer) { _observer = observer; }
    int ii() const { return _ii; }
    void nextIi() { _ii++; }

    void lock()    { _mutex.lock(); }
    bool tryLock() { return _mutex.try_lock(); }
    void unlock()  { _mutex.unlock(); }

private:
    void runP()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
                if (i % 10 == 0) {
                    lock();
                    nextIi();
                    unlock();
                    notify();
                }
            }
        }

    void notify() { _observer->notify(); }  //!!!
    Observer *_observer;
    int _ii;
    std::mutex _mutex;
};

struct MwObserver : public Observer
{
    explicit MwObserver(struct MainWindow *mainWindow) { _mainWindow = mainWindow; }
    virtual void notify();

    MainWindow *_mainWindow;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow() { delete _ui; }
    void upd();

public slots:
    void run() { _core.run(); }

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *_ui;
    MwObserver _observer;
    Core _core;
};

inline void MwObserver::notify() { _mainWindow->upd(); }

#endif
```

-

```
//MainWindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    _ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    _observer(this)
{
    _ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(_ui->pushButtonRun, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(run()));
}

void MainWindow::upd()
{
    _core.lock();
    setWindowTitle(QString::number(_core.ii()));
    _core.unlock();
}
```

Comment: QThread is and has been cross-platform long before std::thread came into being.

Comment: Ummm isn't thread created on the stack ?

Comment: Run your program through a debugger. Which line causes the crash? Note: "Segmentation fault" just means your program tried to read/write a part of your computer's memory that's forbidden. This often happens when you misuse pointers.

Comment: @jksh `void notify() { _observer->notify(); }`

Answer (score 11):

There are multiple problems here, first and most obvious was already noted by perencia. You are returning a pointer to stack variable. In c++ terms it's unacceptable.

Secondly. The crash comes from not using `std::thread`, but from race condition. The Qt event loop does not know about you mutex, so your `setWindowTitle` call is introducing a race, that leads to crash. 
You need to use [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) to post function to the Qts event loop.

Example:
change

```
inline void MwObserver::notify() { _mainWindow->upd(); }
```

to

```
inline void MwObserver::notify() {
    if(!QMetaObject::invokeMethod(_mainWindow, "upd", Qt::QueuedConnection))
        std::cerr << " Failed to invoke method" << std::endl;
}
```

additional includes may apply

Comment: could you hint me what exactly do I have to do? (std::thread *thread = new std::thread(&Core::runP, this); gives the same effect.)

Comment: @ufx this fixes only the problem with stack variable. I'll update the answer with invokeMethod example

Comment: it didn't help me.

Comment: I have the same error in this case. Don't you have?

Answer (score 9):

This updates the GUI from a thread different then the GUI thread! Which is not allowed.
Why not to use QThread and a signal/slot mechanism to update your window title. The Qt framework does the thread switching automatically.

```
class Core : public QObject 
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Core(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

signals:
  void notify();

public slots:
  void nextIi() { _ii++; }
  void runP()
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
      if (i % 10 == 0) {
        nextIi();
        notify();
      }
    }
  }

private:
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(Core);
  int _ii;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT 
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void run() {_th.start();}
    void upd(int ii) {setWindowTitle(QString::number(ii));}

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *_ui;
    Core _core;
    QThread _th;
};

//MainWindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    _ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    _observer(this)
{
  _ui->setupUi(this);

  connect(_ui->pushButtonRun, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(run()));
  connect(&_core, SIGNAL(notify(int)), this, SLOT(upd(int)));
  _core.moveToThread(&_th);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{ 
  delete _ui; 
  _th.quit();
  _th.wait(1000);
}
```

Comment: If it is possible I don't want to make the core dependent of Qt.

Answer (score 7):

You are creating thread on the stack and returning a pointer to that. After `run()` that pointer is no longer valid.

Comment: `std::thread *thread = new std::thread(&Core::runP, this);` gives the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from returning pointer to stack variable and updating GUI from thread object that is not known for QT. I don't see from your code, where you set up `_observer` member of `Core` class. There is no `setObserver` call for `_core` member of `MainWindow` class.

So consructor of `MainWindow` class calls consructor of `_core` member, but after that `_core._observer` contains garbage. I think this is the cause of your `Segmentaion Fault` in call of `notify` method of `Core` class.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to all the problems have already been given, let me summarize.

The program crash has nothing to do with the threading, The problem is that the `_observer` in the `_core` member of `MainWindow`is not set. A call to setObserver must be added.

```
explicit MainWindow( QWidget *parent = nullptr ) :
    QMainWindow( parent ),
    _observer( this )
{
    _core.setObserver( &_observer );
}
```

This will lead to the next problem, that the observer actually calls the `udp` message from another thread, causing a UI update in a different thread context. To solve this, it is easiest to use Qt's `Qt::QueuedConnection`. To enable this we must make `upt()` a slot.

```
public slots:

void run();
void upd();
```

Then we can either call it using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` in

```
inline void MwObserver::notify()
{
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod( _mainWindow, "upd", Qt::QueuedConnection );
}
```

or use a signal / slot connection by deriving `MwObserver` from `QObject`, giving it a signal, and connect that signal to the `upd` slot and raising the signal in `notify`.

```
struct MwObserver 
    : public QObject
    , public Observer
{
    Q_OBJECT;

    signals:
    void sigUpd();

public:
    explicit MwObserver( MainWindow *mainWindow );

    virtual void notify()

    MainWindow *_mainWindow;
};

void MwObserver::notify()
{
    sigUpd();
}

MwObserver::MwObserver( MainWindow *mainWindow )
{
    _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    connect( this, SIGNAL(sigUpd()), _mainWindow, SLOT(upd()) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't used Qt in some time but with X/XMotif on Linux/UNIX the GUI MUST run in the 'main-thread', not spawned threads. Maybe this applies to your situation. Just a thought, have your GUI code run in the main-thread.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to wrap pure C++ code with QObejct instance and fire signals when  this objects receive some notification from pure C++ code.

SO in your case:

```
class MwObserver : public QObject, public Observer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MwObserver(QObject *parent)
      : QObject(parent)
    {}

signals:
    void SomeEvent();

protected:
    // Observer
    void notify() {
       emit SomeEvent();
    }
};
```

Now MainWindow should connect some slot to signal provided this way and everything should work out of the box (Qt will do thread jumping behind the scenes).

In [your code form comment](http://pastebin.com/GBjnK5Va) the crash is caused by invalid use of temporary object. This is **INVALID C++** code no mater what kind of object is returned:

```
std::thread *run()
{
    std::thread thread(&Core::runP, this);
    thread.detach();
    return &thread;
 }
```

You cant  return a pointer to local object of the function method, since this object becomes invalid immediately when you return a function. This is basic C++ knowledge.

Comment: see update. Also I recommend you to abandon use of threads. They are relay hard to learn and maintain. Mistakes have made are indicating that you have problems with basic knowledge about C++ itself. So first learn basic stuff before you use threads.

Comment: I can change to `void`. Anyway I didn't use returning value of this function yet. What did I do wrong here? http://pastebin.com/GBjnK5Va